# Jest test fails "Cannot find module 'images/myimage.png' from SignInOrRegister.js" with image size class @1x,@2x,@3x,@4x

Tags: react-native, jestjs

My snapshot tests in Jest are failing after adding multiple size classes of my image.

In a file **SignInOrRegister.js**, I have an image defined like so:

`<Image source={require('./images/myimage.png')} />`

In **images** I have multiple sizes of the same image named like so:
**myimage@1x.png**
**myimage@2x.png**
**myimage@3x.png**
**myimage@4x.png**

When I run my jest snapshot test, then it fails. Here is the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import SignInOrRegister from '../SignInOrRegister';

test('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<SignInOrRegister />).toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

Here is the error I get when running it:

```
> jest tests --updateSnapshot

 FAIL  src/pages/__tests__/SignInOrRegister.test.js
  ● Console

    console.error node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:8060
      The above error occurred in the <SignInOrRegister> component:
          in SignInOrRegister (at SignInOrRegister.test.js:6)

      Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
      Visit  to learn more about error boundaries.

  ● renders correctly

    Cannot find module './images/myimage.png' from 'SignInOrRegister.js'

      25 |             <View style={styles.logoViewStyle}>
      26 |               <Image
    > 27 |                 source={require('./images/myimage.png')}
         |                   ^
      28 |                 style={styles.logoStyle}
      29 |               />
      30 |             </View>

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:221:17)
      at SignInOrRegister.render (src/pages/SignInOrRegister.js:27:19)
      at finishClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6625:31)
      at updateClassComponent (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:6588:10)
      at beginWork (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:7413:16)
```

I can't seem to find any other questions like this anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to name the images like so:

**myimage.png**
**myimage@2x.png**
**myimage@3x.png**
**myimage@4x.png**

So the first image should not have **@1x**

Any time the images have changed it's also suggested to restart the metro bundler, build your app and then run your snapshot tests again.

Comment: There is no 4x image size in react-native docs, only up to 3x. Where did you get it from?